# How to update from UIProgressBar on main thread in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, download

i am using one method to download video files inside document directory and it worked perfectly fine, I am using below code which is downloading video in background, however while downloading i need to update progress bar also as how much is downloaded, however main thread is not updating.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: videoURL];

    NSString *pathToDocs = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",self.titleString];
    [data writeToFile:[pathToDocs stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"File %@ successfully saved", filename);

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Succesfully Downloaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to update Progress on main thread like this,

```
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: videoURL];

        NSString *pathToDocs = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",self.titleString];
        [data writeToFile:[pathToDocs stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"File %@ successfully saved", filename);

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Succesfully Downloaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            //Task you want perform on mainQueue
            //Control Progressbar here

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataWithContentsOfURL` won't return a status; it simply blocks the thread until the complete download is done.  You need to use something asynchronous that reports progress.

Take a look at AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#file-upload-with-progress-callback) as it's designed to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to monitor the progress of a download, you should consider using [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE), where you can use the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` method [`didReceiveData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveData%3a) to update your UI regarding the progress.

If you want to know how much data is expected, you can often use [`didReceiveResponse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011348-CH1-SW3), which may, for HTTP URLs, contain the expected file size. (Not all web servers provide that, though.)

As Richard suggested, you may want to look into using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), as it can simplify your programming effort.